# bokeh datepicker is giving error in IE

Tags: python, bokeh

I am new to bokeh. I was trying to interactively update a graph by picking date from date picker. I can not see the date picker default value though it is set and I get

> > error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): ValueError('Unknown string format',)" error while trying to change the date.

```
dpk = DatePicker(min_date=min((data['Date'])).date(),
             max_date=max((data['Date'])).date(),
             value=dt.date(2017,1,9))
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    src = ColumnDataSource(data[data['Date'] == dpk.value].sort_values('Time'))
    source.data.update(src.data)   
    dpk.on_change('value',update_plot)
    curdoc().add_root(row(plot,dpk)) 
    curdoc().title = "datepicker"
```